# Formating date string with strtotime and date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have date string (Example `'2014-06-06 12:24:48'`). I what display with other format (Example `'06.06.2014 (12:24:48)'`).

```
$date = '2014-06-06 12:24:48';
echo date('d-m-Y (H:i:s)', strtotime($date));
```

Does the output date would be always the same as input date? For any valid input date.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s') === date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))); 
// Always true?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s') === date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))); 
// Always true?
```

While that statement will be true most of the time, it will **not always** be true because the left `(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` is evaluated after the right `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, so if the code is run a nanosecond before the second digit is about to change, the two dates will have different second digits.

You can verify that these two statements are not always equal by running the code below, which will eventually print "False".

```
while(true) {
  $x = (date('Y-m-d H:i:s') === date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
  if(!$x) {
    exit("False");
  }
}
```

However, if you provide the same timestamp to each `date` call, then the statements will always be equal

```
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time) === date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time))); 
//Always true
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The two dates will always be the same date and time - in different formats:

```
2014-06-06 12:24:48
06-06-2014 (12:24:48)
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/XFdBGzUk)

**EDIT**

The statement:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s') === date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

will <del>always</del> usually be true (*See **Edit 2** below*).

The second parameter on `date()` defaults to the current timestamp.

`strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` is the current timestamp.

So the two statements:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

and

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```

are logically the same.

[**Another demo**](http://codepad.org/BL7V3ALJ)

**Edit 2**

[FuzzyTree's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094571/formating-date-string-with-strtotime-and-date/24094600#answer-24101922) points out that, while the two statements are usually true, they will not always be true. See his answer for more details.

Comment: @sectus See edit - not really sure what you mean by any date. Yes, this logic will apply to any date. A datetime is always the same datetime regardless of the format.

Comment: The statement will not always be true see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change format of date like

```
$date = '2014-06-06 12:24:48';
echo date('d-m-Y (H:i:s)', strtotime($date));
```

For more format :- http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.date.php

the output will not be same as your input date it's depend on what you entered date format
so if your date format is:-

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and input date format is

```
$input_date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

then you need to convert input date format to match with other date like

```
$input_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($inputdate));
```

else your input date format is same then no need to convert

then match `if($date == $input_date)`